# The Key Idea of the Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability

The law of large numbers (LLN) says: If I do a lot of randomized experiments on an event E, then for an (imagined) infinite number of such experiments the relative frequency of E approaches the theoretical probability P(E) arbitrarily closely.

Now, the proof looks very technical, but I want to understand the basic idea of why the LLN is true and provable. IMO the key background premise, from which LLN more or less already "proves" itself, is that the theoretical probability of E is chosen specifically to match the relative frequencies expected from randomized experiments about E. In that case it is of course not very impressive that one can prove this connection.

Without the above premise there is no LLN. For example, for a coin toss I can set P (heads) = 0.1 and P (tails) = 0.9, and that's a valid (though not practical) probability function. But in such a case there's no LLN because no relative frequency will converge against the postulated probabilities.

To you pro mathematicians: are both my points right?

Comment: There is a LLN for the imbalanced coin too: Essentially it says that "if you toss your coin often enough, then almost surely the ratio $\frac{\text{heads}}{\text{all tosses}}$ will approach $0.1$". In fact, there are LLNs that don't even require identical distribution, so similar formulations exist also if you throw a different coin each time etc. Also there is almost a century of work when it comes to improving the proof of different LLNs, I had a small part in that: https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.03967, so saying that it "proves itself" might not be quite accurate :)

Comment: The main idea is to compute the variance of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ when $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. with finite variance.

Comment: But why can we prove a mathematical law (LLN) that tells us what to expect in reality, for the example of a coin toss that the relative frequency heads/all_tosses converges to the true probability P(heads)? What is that connection between the empirical "relative frequency" and the mathematical "probability" that makes LLN a mathematical law of certainty? My guess: LLN only works if we define - let's use coin toss as an example - h(heads) = heads/tosses AND P(heads) = heads/tosses. Now I can see how LLN is a mathematical theorem. But if we assume P(heads) = 0.1 then no way LLN is valid.